# :after tag not working properly with <li>

Tags: html, css

I want to display a `content"--"` after every list items but when i use `li:after` then the content comes below the list items and when i use `a:after` then the content correctly comes after the list items. However i want the `content"--"` to be associated with the `<li>` and not the `<a>` because when i will be using `a:hover` then there will be some problem. Here is the code. Can anyone help?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="group">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS***

```
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    background:gray;
}

li {
    float:left;
    padding-left:30px;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}

li:after{ content:'--'; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the element `:after` is rendered after the `a` tag, since you have this into the a tag:

```
a {
  display:block;
}
```

The `:after` content is in the next level pushed by the a `block` tag. Change this and you see the change:

```
a {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6YuQ8/3/**